# Killer E2200 driver for XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers

Really sorry if this is the wrong place to post this, but I'm looking for a Windows XP (32 bit) driver for this NIC:

> Killer e2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.3)

I've tried searching and all I can find is adware trojans!

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Basically: there aren't any; [the manufacturer doesn't make any](http://www.killernetworking.com/support/driver-downloads/item/drivers-only) (only Windows 7+) so your NIC is not XP compatible.

Comment: It should work without a driver and/or the just the generic LAN driver at the very least.  You could in theory attempt to modify the .INF file yourself.  The manufacture specific features are unlikely going to work in Windows XP for obvious reasons.

Comment: It's an XP Hyper-V VM, the generic driver doesn't seem to work, or be recognised as the right one.

Comment: Generic drivers for NICs do not exist. However in a VM you are not accessing the NIC directly anyway, so you cannot use the hardware driver even if it did exist. What you need is the Microsoft Hyper-V NIC driver.

Comment: I love that there are no edits to this question, no reasons given as to why it is a low quality question, but plenty of downvotes and upvotes. Would really like to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several aspects to this:

1. XP drivers for your card apparently aren't supplied by the manufacturer so there is no "officially supported" method to use it under XP. Thankfully, as SuperUsers, we don't care about official support.
2. The card is an AR8161 chip, so you can use ordinary Atheros drivers for it, the following page details how:

http://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/guide-turn-your-killer-e2200-nic-into-qualcomm-atheros-ar8161.198899/

3. Neither of the above is relevant when running in a Hyper-V VM. In a VM the guest has no access to the real hardware so cannot use for drivers for your physical hardware.

---

In a VM the hypervisor emulates a virtual network adapter. What you need is a driver for the Hyper-V network adapter you have chosen. There are two different Hyper-V network adapters as documented [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc770380.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

- A network adapter requires a virtual machine driver in order to work, but offers better performance. This driver is included with some newer versions of Windows. On all other supported operating systems [including Windows XP], **install integration services in the guest operating system to install the virtual machine driver**. For instructions, see [Install a Guest Operating System.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc742460.aspx)
- A legacy network adapter works without installing a virtual machine driver. The legacy network adapter emulates a physical network adapter, multiport DEC 21140 10/100TX 100 MB. According to Microsoft, you cannot use the legacy adapter mode in Windows Server 2003 64-bit (this likely applies to Windows XP 64-bit as well). However, there is a workaround to force it to work in an unsupported mode using Vista drivers - [see here.](https://aliiraza.wordpress.com/2013/02/03/hyper-v-how-to-install-legacy-network-driver-for-windows-server-2003-virtual-machine/)

Answer (score 1):

try to install driver for [killer 2100](https://www.visiontek.com/download-drivers.html) i think this network card not much different from 2200, but for her have a driver for WinXP 32bit